# UIAlertView and upside down orientation

Tags: ios, uialertview, autorotate

I've got the issue that reproduces on iPhone with iOS>=8
The entire interface is rotating correctly for all possible screen orientations. But when UIAlertView is shown it's not rotated to upside down orientation.
[image]

I've tried different solutions found on SO but nothing is helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/wangyangcc/FYAlertManage